# удаление динамического массива указателей на массивы интов

Tags: c++, память

Как правильно удалить все динамические данные в таком случае?

```
int main()
{
    const int n = 10; const int m = 10;
    int **p;
    p = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m;j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = i + j;
            cout << p[i][j] <<"\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

В обратном порядке:

```
p = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    p[i] = new int[m];

.........

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[] p[i];
delete[] p;
```